# I am trying to create a Windows Forms Application that will loop through a series of numbers and divide each one with a Divisor

Tags: c#, winforms, loops, modulus

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        int numberLoops;
        int divisor;
        int answer;
        answer = 0;

        numberLoops = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        divisor = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        for  (int i = 0; i < numberLoops; i++)
        {

            if (numberLoops % divisor == 0)
            {
                answer = divisor;

            }



           listBox1.Items.Add(answer.ToString());
```

If the division has no remainder then display
the value in the ListBox. Use the modulus operator to determine the remainder.

```
For (i = 0 to max)
result = i % divisor
```

Comment: What's the problem you are facing

Comment: and the question is?

Comment: Thanks for replying guys, I am a beginner and having trouble listing the values without a remainder  in the listbox. The listbox is listing the number of loops, I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

> For (i = 0 to max) result = i % divisor

Looks like you want to do this

```
listBox1.Items.Clear();

if(divisor != 0)
{
     for  (int i = divisor; i < numberLoops; i++)
     {
          if(i% divisor == 0) listBox1.Items.Add(i.ToString());
     }
}
```

As a beginner you could start with above approach, but there is another approach which uses `Linq`

```
var values = Enumerable.Range(divisor, numberLoops-divisor)
          .Where(x=> x%divisor ==0)
          .ToArray();

listBox1.Items.AddRange(values.ToArray());
```

Comment: Great going all the best.

Answer (score 0):

```
listBox1.Items.Clear();
for (int i = divisor; i <= numberLoops; i++)
{
    if (i % divisor == 0)
    {
        answer = i;
        listBox1.Items.Add(answer.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Hari, I found a simpler way to get it working but I will defiantly use your answer and learn from it. Much appreciated.